# Question about insert from TK form to csv file

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv, tkinter, export-to-csv

I am trying to get some info from TK form that i built to new CSV file, unfortunately i am getting some Errors.
The code:

```
def sub_func():
    with open('Players.csv','w') as df:
        df = pd.DataFrame
        i=len(df.index)
        data=[]
        data.append(entry_box1.get())
        data.append(entry_box2.get())
        data.append(entry_box3.get())
        data.append(entry_box4.get())

        if i==4:
            df.loc[i,:]=data
```

The Errors:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\_init.py", line 1883, in __call_
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/test11/Final Project/registration form.py", line 23, in sub_func
    i=len(df.index)
TypeError: object of type 'pandas._libs.properties.AxisProperty' has no len()
```

Comment: Change this line i=len(list(df.['index']))

Comment: i tried, still the Error:i=len(list(df['index']))
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Comment: can you show csv file headers, what you are trying to do in this line?

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems in your code:

1. The file is opened as `df`, but `df` is overwritten on the next line
2. `df = pd.DataFrame` does not return anything as it would need parenthesis () to create a dataframe. This means that `df` does not exist -> error comes when you try to take length of 'nothing'.

Solution:

```
df = pd.read_csv('./Players')  # Make sure that the file is in the same directory
i = len(df.index)
```

Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but you might need to work on the rest of the code, too.